# Modification for Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I want to know, when the start vertex s is given, the shortest path is computed only if a vertex is no more than three edges away from the start vertex.

I thought of doing this by counting the number of parents, and if number_of_parents<=3 then it is a valid path.

Please can someone clarify this for me using the algorithm?

Below is the standard Dijkstra Algorithm.

```
Dijkstra(G,W,s)
   Initialize_Single_Source(G,s)
   S= {}
   Q = V[G]
   while Q != {} do
      u = extract_min(Q)
      S = S U {u}
      for each vertex v element of Adj[u] do
                 relax(u,v,w)
```

Comment: "I thought of doing this" Go ahead and do this, then ask a question.

Comment: Why not just create a new graph, which only contains all nodes which are at most 3 edges  away from the source and use dijkstra algorithm on that graph. You can create the smaller graph by doing 3 iterations of BFS, all visited nodes belong in your smaller graph.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of a vertex we use array L to determine levels, i.e., how far a node is from the source

```
Dijkstra(G,W, s)
   Initialize_Single_Source(G,s)
   S= {}
   Q = V[G]
   L = {an array to determine levels of each node, 
    initially all nodes have level "infinite" except for s who has level 0}
   while Q != {} do
      u = extract_min(Q)
      u_level = L[u]
      if(u_level > 3){
        ignore u and don't add it to S;
        continue;
      }
      S = S U {u}
      for each vertex v element of Adj[u] do
                 relax(u,v,w)
                 in relax function you put L[v] = min(L[v], u_level + 1);
```

Comment: I think this is the correct way.. thanks

Comment: We are not a coding service for lazy homeworkers. This answer does not help anyone, OP the least, because he will not learn anything.

Comment: I hope you get nothing but people like this as co-workers for a few years so you learn the lesson @Olaf is trying to teach.